# Allowing a particular user to access a blocked site for a limited time

Tags: squid

I have configured squid proxy server and blocked Facebook site. I need to give permission for a particular user to access Facebook for a limited time. For that how to modify the configuration file. this the screen shot of the configuration file.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dyIM.png) (The font size is small, so please zoom the image)

In this line,

```
http_access deny Facebook all !allowip118 !allowip113 !allowip108 !allowip18
```

What is configured here ?. Facebook is denied but what !allowip113 indicates ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `!allowip...` records are exceptions for certain IPs. You would need to define a new one (following the syntax of the existing acl src rules) and then just add that name to the list.

So if you start with:

```
http_access deny facebook all !allowip118 !allowip113 !allowip108 !allowip18
```

You end with:

```
acl allowbob src 192.168.0.34
http_access deny facebook all !allowip118 !allowip113 !allowip108 !allowip18 !allowbob
```

Or instead of editing the deny, add an explicit allow for `allowbob`:

```
http_access allow facebook allowbob
```

If you need to time-limit this, say you wanted to explicitly allow Bob to use Facebook between 6pm and 8am, you could slip the following in before the `deny facebook` record:

```
acl facebooktime time MTWHF 18:00-8:00
http_access allow facebook facebooktime allowbob
```