# How to configure a firewall that only allows a few webpages and dropbox and U1 services?

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, ubuntu-one, firewall, dropbox

Can anyone give a step-by-step **how-to** that explains how to

1. block all outgoing internet traffic to all websites, but allows only a selected list (needed for working, fi. online dictionaries)
2. allows Dropbox and Ubuntu One to do their job (so backups will not be lost and things get synced)
3. that can be switched off easily after a period of hard work

I have no knowledge whatsoever of networking, about hosts, IPs, subnets, subnetmasks, ports, ipconfig or whatever.
In the past I always used firestarter to block all my outgoing traffic apart from a few webpages. **Firestarter** does not do the trick anymore. If I add an outgoing whitelist the policies just don't apply. With **gufw** I can't work because it is overtly complicated.

The use case: I need to stay focused on my work and thus I need easy access to the internet to be less easy. Thanks in advance on behalf of all networking noobs.

---

#### Edit/Update on why gufw is hard to use

What is hard to understand on **gufw** is how to define policies. In the *Add Rules* dialogue I do not understand

- in the *simple* tab, whether I should choose TCP or UDP or both. Whether I should choose a port or a service, what the dangers are of this and how to find the name of this port or service
- in the *advanced* tab, whether I should choose TCP or UDP or both and what the values of the from and to fields should be (especially the port number). Also why should I specify a *from* field? That's localhost right?

Comment: What documentation are you following on gufw and what part do you not understand? Without a specific question we would be repeating the documentation you are already reading. Also, for the most part, the firewall in Linux is not designed to block / allow sites, although you can do so, most people use a proxy. To use iptables (gufw) you need a white list of servers (ip addresses + port). If you do not understand networking try http://bodhizazen.net/Tutorials/iptables

Comment: OK. You make an absolutely valid point. I'll edit. A proxy is fine for me too. Thanks for the nice webpage.

Comment: A firewall is probably overkill here. Unless you're using using lots of non-browser based time sinks, you can find browser addons which can impose various restrictions. See, eg, LeechBlock for Firefox (blacklists sites rather than a whitelist, but I expect you can find a whitelist if you prefer).

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I read the page you offered. Interesting. A tiny bit too difficult for me. Quite frankly, firestarter is deprecated, but it did the job very intuitively for me. Do you feel like answering the question explaining how to allow dropbox and a few websites with gufw? Would really make my day.

Comment: you need to know the ip address of the servers you want to allow. Allow server 1, allow server 2 ... then deny all. See also http://blog.bodhizazen.net/linux/firewall-ubuntu-gufw/

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I can't access that website. I am trying to split the quesiton up. First part = http://askubuntu.com/questions/330066/how-to-block-all-but-one-or-two-websites-without-browser-extensions?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the first time somebody wanted to block the distraction of the internet while allowing some websites. Projects like SelfControl and FocalFilter have existed for a while. There has been a port to Linux of SelfControl and we have a few questions that travel down the same path:

- http://svn.jklmnop.net/projects/SelfControl.html
- [SelfControl-like filtering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62146/selfcontrol-like-filtering)
- "Get Shit Done": [How to block websites temporarily?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71817/how-to-block-websites-temporarily)
- Timed-allowed websites with Squid/Dansguardian: [Allowing a particular user to access a blocked site for a limited time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305277/allowing-a-particular-user-to-access-a-blocked-site-for-a-limited-time/305288#305288)

Comment: Hi Oli, I know these services and I will most likely resort temporarily to [leechblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/leechblock/). I know, however, it can also be done with a firewall (thus also blocking games, rss and the like). Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: The self-control port is a firewall-based solution.

Comment: I'd have to retry self-control. I tried it a month ago on 13.04, but it had several bugs.

Comment: Update: the current trunk of self-control is working again on 13.04. I think Ubuntu needs a mature application that not only controls network activity, but applications as such.